# digest authentication with custom login

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am working on a project of developing a web UI. The project requires .NET implementation. I currently published the website on Windows server 2008 with IIS 7.5 for testing. The project asks for and login/out page as the entrance to the main UI. The login/out page should asks for username and password with some security questions. And it also enables user to change and save the password. The authentication technique has to be implemented using digested authentication.

I have already tested the digest authentication after enabling it in IIS. It works good with popping up a window asking for the username and password.However, I have a doubt whether the digest authentication allows for customized login/out page and ability of changing and saving the password (which will most likely be realized with form authentication to the best of my knowledge). I believe there might be (or not?) some ways of doing it, anyone can guide me?